# Need help to write a regular expression statement (Newbie alert!)

Tags: regex

I use photobucket to host my imagery for my ebay ads when I sell things, so I copy the html out of photobucket into notepad, and I'm always left the `<img>` tag being wrapped in photobucket's `<a>` tag, and I have to go through each line and manually delete each `<a></a>`,  which on 26 lines across multiple items can soon equate too hundreds of "highlight and delete" actions.
I already do a search for the closing tag `</a>` and just do a "replace" with nothing, thus removing it, but the string I cannot fathom to remove, due to the image file name being different on every line is as the following example demonstrates:
So it's essentially the section of the anchor tag up to and including the `>` I need to be able to remove on a mass scale - Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<a href="http://s1297.photobucket.com/user/eye/media/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC02424_zpslt9m0cuu.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag35/eye/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC02424c_zpslt9m0cuu.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo DSC05653_zpslt9m0cuu.jpg"/></a>
<a href="http://s1297.photobucket.com/user/eye/media/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC04444_zpspkgjw6vf.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag35/eye/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC04444_zpspkgjw6vf.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo DSC05654_zpspkgjw6vf.jpg"/></a>
<a href="http://s1297.photobucket.com/user/eye/media/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC05655_zpsxuev7czs.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag35/eye/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC05655_zpsxuev7czs.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo DSC05655_zpsxuev7czs.jpg"/></a>
<a href="http://s1297.photobucket.com/user/eye/media/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC06624_zpsifjidypy.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag35/eye/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC06624_zpsifjidypy.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo DSC05656_zpsifjidypy.jpg"/></a>
<a href="http://s1297.photobucket.com/user/eye/media/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC07777_zpsacyjrnnr.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag35/eye/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC07777_zpsacyjrnnr.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo DSC05663_zpsacyjrnnr.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: just to be sure, you want to capture `<a href="http://s1297.photobucket.com/user/eye/media/Programmes/Yes%20joblot/DSC02424_zpslt9m0cuu.jpg.html" target="_blank">`?

Comment: Verbatim from the tag [tag:regex] description: "Even if you are not well versed in regexes, it's better to show us what you've tried than simply asking the community to solve your problem."

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct everything encapsulated within the first section of the anchor tag so <a href="somthing here" target="_blank">

Comment: All I have I done to date is do Control + F, which pops up the find and replace box, and I have gone to the "replace tab" and entered </a> into the "find what" box, and then left the "replace" box blank - Press enter and it removes all instances of the closing </a> tag, that's the simple part, its the first section of the anchor tag Im trying to remove, and as I wouldn't know where to start writing regex to remove this first anchor section, I seek someone more knowledgeable to assist me if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="[^"]+?" target="_blank">
```

would do what you want, or even more general:

```
<a href=[^>]+?>
```